# Pasar el valor de un Label a otra pagina aspx con c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

¿Cómo puedo pasar una variable Label que me almacena un nombre a otra página aspx llamada Registros?
Abro la página Registros por medio de un botón como una ventana emergente:

```
 protected void Ver_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string vtn = "window.open('VerDetalle.aspx','Dates','scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes','height=90', 'width=50')";
    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "popup", vtn, true);
}
```

Por esa razón no pretendo utilizar Response.Redirect. Podrían ayudarme con alguna otra forma?

Comment: La puedes pasar por querystring

Comment: Se lo puedes mandar por GET en la url algo así string vtn = "window.open('VerDetalle.aspx?valor=tuvalor','Dates','scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes','height=90', 'width=50')"; y recogerlo en "VerDetalle" algo así Request.Querystring("valor")

Comment: Ok, muchas gracias!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recomendaria que si vas a obtener un valor de la pagina no la tomes nunca de un label, si quieres mostrarla esta bien, pero ademas asigna el valor a un `hidden` de asp.net, asi podras tomarlo cuando se realiza el post

```
protected void Ver_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var valor = Hidden1.Value;
    string url = string.Format("'VerDetalle.aspx?keyname={0}'", valor);

    string vtn = "window.open(url,'Dates','scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes','height=90', 'width=50')";

    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "popup", vtn, true);
}
```

En la pagina `VerDetalle.aspx` usaras

```
var valor = Request.QueryString["keyname"];
```

para obtener el valor que envies en la url